# How do I test F# in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, f#-unquote

I need a sane solution to test my f# code. 
I think that `unqote` is really nice library, 
and i guess that `fuchu` is helpful to group the test.

```
namespace Frank
module MyTest =
  open Fuchu 
  open Swensen.Unquote
  [<Tests>]
  let t = 
    testCase "1" <| fun _ ->  
      test <@ 1 + 1  = 3 @>
```

It works fine from `fsi`

```
#load "Scripts/load-references-debug.fsx"
open Fuchu
#load "regexTest.fs"
open Frank.MyTest
run t
```

or as a console application as described in https://github.com/mausch/Fuchu

```
open Fuchu
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = defaultMainThisAssembly args
```

with the wonderful output

```
1: Failed: 

1 + 1 = 3
2 = 3
false

1 tests run: 0 passed, 0 ignored, 1 failed, 0 errored (00:00:00.0024090)
```

But i believe also in visual Studio is a mechanism to Discover and run specific tess, which has the `Test Exporer` window and the `Test\run\All Tests` menue entry.

Unfortunately this is not working for me, as Visal Studio 2015 does not discover those tests

```
------ Discover test started ------
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.0220136) ==========
```

I have seen this working, even on my machine. But now I didn't. I like to get this orking, by understanding how the test discovery works in VS2015.

Comment: I believe Fuchu by itself doesn't support MSTest discovery. You need to install another framework, like NUnit or xUnit, and use a bridge from Fuchu to it.

Comment: To use the VS Test Explorer, if you are using NUnit then you need to load the NUnit test adapter. There are adaptors for versions [2.x](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/) and [3.x](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/)

Comment: The testing examples in F# for Fun and Profit are a bit dated. I ran into this a few weeks ago when using the FuChu example.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I am happy with `unquote` and just need a way to organize and run tests. I guess `fuchu` does that, but the documentation is sparse. The VS test explorer would be nice too, it worked with `xUnit`, but only when I installed the `xunit.runner.visualstudio` via PM-Console, not when I used `paket`. So I am still up to a way to organize unquote test and run them in VS-TestExplorer.

Comment: You're saying that you have seen this working on your machine? VS can be a little temperamental with test discovery, also with mstest. Sometimes a "Rebuild solution" does the job for me, to get it back on track if the test discovery engine gets stuck. Or close VS, and kill the process `vstest.discoveryengine` and `vstest.executionengine` if any are still running.

Answer (score 1):

Could you make `MyTest.t` a function?

```
[<Test>]
let t () =
   // ...
```

Right now it is defined as a property and I don't think NUnit will see this as a test.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a Visual Studio test adapter for Fuchu. The source is at https://github.com/interactsw/fuchu-adapter and it's available from github as the [Fuchu.Adapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fuchu.Adapter/) package. This enables Fuchu tests to show up in Visual Studio's **Test Explorer** window.